# Is there a way to use vim keys to manipulate Strings in java?

Tags: java, vim

In vim, for string

```
"Hello, today is the first day of your life"
```

to remove Hello, and make t in today uppercase

I use

```
^[0df ~
```

In Java, I probably need more code to do this. 
Is there any library for java that will allow to manipulate text as you do it in vi?

```
String result = vilibrary.execute("Hello, today is the first day ...", "^[0df ~", viins);
```

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question directly, although it does offer a possible hacky solution.

I've written a little bash script called `qvim`. It's basically a thin wrapper around `vim`, invoking it with `-` (so that it reads stdin into the initial unnamed buffer) and then automatically passes all command-line arguments through as `-c` values, so they'll be executed as vim command-line commands. It then adds its own `-c` argument with value `wq! $QVIM_FILENAME`, where the variable is a temp file which is then `cat`ted. This provides a shell command-line interface to vim.

Here's `qvim`:

```
#!/bin/bash

QVIM_FILENAME="$(mktemp /tmp/qvim-XXXXXXXXXX)";

if [[ "$QVIM_VERBOSE" == '1' ]]; then
    vim - "${@/#/-c}" -c "wq! $QVIM_FILENAME";
else
    vim - "${@/#/-c}" -c "wq! $QVIM_FILENAME" >/dev/null 2>&1;
fi;
rc=$?;

if [[ -e "$QVIM_FILENAME" ]]; then
    cat -- "$QVIM_FILENAME";
    rm -f -- "$QVIM_FILENAME";
fi;

exit $rc;
```

Thus you can do this in the shell:

```
> echo 'Hello, today is the first day of your life'| qvim 'normal 0df ~';
Today is the first day of your life
```

You could theoretically call this in a system command from a Java program, although you'd have to be careful about quoting the input string and the vim command.

As I said, hacky.